# Why did Daryl Van Horne target Felicia?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-witches-of-eastwick

From the moment that Daryl moved to Eastwick, Felicia seemed to be tormented by him.

The moment that Felicia hears that someone (later revealed to be Daryl) bought the Lennox mansion, she drops what she is carrying and goes on a rant to her husband:

> **Felicia:** I have this feeling, Clyde. I have the most terrible feeling. Something... Something crawling inside me. Something evil.
>   Only it's more than a feeling. Something is happening, Clyde.

Later at a concert, Felicia makes a comment about Daryl's name and Sukie's pearls snap off of her neck sending Felicia tumbling down the stairs, breaking her leg.

After this incident, Felicia goes mad trying to warn everyone in town that there is evil going on in Daryl's mansion.  Daryl eventually sends her into a fit of madness with having her vomit cherry seeds that him and the three women at his house are eating.  Felicia's husband finally snaps and proceeds to kill her.

**What is the purpose for Daryl tormenting Felicia the way that he did?**

Comment: I hate the way that Hollywood usually portrays Christians, but given her behavior towards not only Darryl and the women, but also her husband and just her overall attitude... wouldn't you dislike her? Even had she NOT presented an obstacle for Darryl Van Horne, she was also portrayed as a very arrogant and self-righteous woman.

Answer (score 3):

As a god fearing woman, she knows all to well of the evil that the house possesses,and that Daryl is actually Satan. She is extremely vocal about it and Daryl See's her as a threat. So he causes her breakdown (to make the town think that she's going mad) before everyone realizes that she's right about him

Answer (score 0):

I think the narrative is designed to encourage dislike of Felicia at first and the movie then brings us around to her point of view.

Anyway, here's an answer to the original question:
Darryl Van Horne targets Felicia because she is the one who sees he is the devil and she (unlike the rest of the town) refuses to turn a blind eye.